# Alert de objetos ASP.NET en JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola quisiera saber si puedo hacer algo así en ASP.NET,porque saben algo así necesito hacer , por favor no me coman si es una pregunta mala, yo lo veo más bien como un reto :3

```js
 var idt = 2;
function detailTry(idt) {
  alert(
    '@Html.ActionLink("Check Request", "Details", "Request", new { id = idt })'
  );

}
```

Dice qe idt no existe cuando lo paso sin importar que haga , en mi caso lo obtengo de otra función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El contenido del alert es un string para javascript mientras que para razor es una url de controller, solo falta asignarle esa parte a tu idt que esta mezclada.

```js
function detailTry(idt) {
  var cadena = '@Html.ActionLink("Check Request", "Details", "Request", new { id = "JSVar" })';
 cadena = cadena.replace("JSVar",idt);
  alert(cadena);
}
detailTry(2);
```

[Ejemplo en MVC.Net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HTdVjB)

Comment: Visual no me deja hacer esto ... justo en la comilla simple antes del mas me marca un error que dice "to many characters in character literal"

Comment: No debería ser problema porque el alert es un string concanetado, generalo antes.

Comment: Pero que crees ... u.u

Comment: Creo que falta mandar llamar a la función y enviar el parámetro `idt` ;)

Comment: Así es, y le asigne tu variable con un replace, lo toma perfecto

Comment: Súper gracias me súper sirvió